# How to debug password encrypted SSIS package with Visual Studio?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2019, ssis-projects

We are going to have multiple developers creating SSIS packages for a data archiving solution.  We are using Visual Studio 2019 and SQL Server Integration Services Projects 3.5.

The project will need to have some sensitive data in it that needs to be encrypted when deployed, so we are planning to encrypt the data with a password that administrators will know.

I changed the protection level of the packages I have created so far to EncryptAllWithPassword.  When I load the package in Visual Studio, I am prompted to enter a password.  I enter the password, and the package opens correctly.

My SSIS project specifies which package to run on startup (StartAction = ExecutePackage).  However, when I try to debug the package, I get the following error:

> Error: 0xC0014037 at {B1137476-D6BB-43BB-9316-FCE26D246AB2}: The package is encrypted with a password. The password was not specified, or is not correct.

This makes sense.  The package is password protected.  I need to enter the password.

There is no prompt to enter a password.  I see no places in the Visual Studio solution or project to enter a password at runtime.

How can I debug an SSIS package in SQL Server Integration Services Projects 3.5 for Visual Studio 2019 when the package requires a password?

The project configuration property InteractiveMode is set to True, so Visual Studio should be able to display a UI.

Comment: When you open a project, or package, that is encrypted with a password, Visual Studio Prompts you for said password. I *assume* the entire project is, which means VS will prompt this before the project opens. You *can* cancel this, however, then you won't load any sensitive data in the project.

Comment: @Larnu I can open the project fine. However, I cannot debug the project. If I press Play to enter the debugger, I get the error I mentioned. I don't see a way to enter a password for the debugger. I found plenty of articles on the Internet about password protecting packages, but I did not see anything related to debugging a password-protected package in Visual Studio.

Comment: The debugger doesn't need the password, provided you provided it previously when you opened the project.

Comment: @Larnu Hmm, I wonder if the Visual Studio SSIS extension has a bug when running nested password-protected packages.  It just did not work for me.  I have several nested packages so far, and I used the same password on all of the packages.  I was able to open them all successfully.